# Slow loading times bringing Firestore data into webapp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to Firebase and Firestore and have currently only created small demo applications using small amounts of data thus far. Please forgive my lack of knowledge concerning best practises for using large amounts of data in web applications.

We are currently looking at building an application with a lot of data - Potentially millions of Firestore documents - But struggling to load even 20,000 documents without having to wait around 10 seconds for the data to load. We want to understand better how to significantly reduce this loading time but as I'm only just finishing university I don't have the knowledge as yet.

As an example, I have set up [this basic JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr2pxL03/) which demonstrates the slow loading times getting around 20,000 documents into a simple text area.

What I would be really grateful to know is if someone with a good knowledge of building Firebase/Firestore applications can explain best practices for getting data into an application efficiently and quickly without these slow loading times. Perhaps using the JSFiddle to demonstrate. I am certain the answer lies within the code as Firebase has been used for huge data applications and copes with these well so I just need some guidance on how to best bring in data.

As I've mentioned, I'm only just about to graduate and all my Javascript and Firebase knowledge is self taught - And so not very good - But I would rally like to understand where I'm going wrong and what is the best approach for this issue.

Many thanks in advance,

```
George
```

Comment: I think that you may want to display a certain amount of data in advance then continue to show them later when user scroll down or click read more button. I don't think that showing all of them at once is a good idea.

Comment: I believe this is where the term 'lazy loading' comes in am i correct? Which allows you to stagger the number of results displayed? But how would I go about implementing this

Comment: It depends on the stack that you are working on. For example, Ionic has VirtualScoll https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/

Comment: The big question here is; why are you loading 20,000 documents? That's a pretty good size dataset (depending on what is stored in each) and may overload the memory on a device. Can you load a sub-set of that instead or maybe use pagination to load smaller chunks?